# How do I align mat-table/table content to the top of the cell?

Tags: css, angular, html-table, mat-table

Such as in this sample application: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhhqh8?file=src/app/app.component.css)

I have a table where the data in the cells are all different heights, but instead of aligning the content to the center.

I want to align content in each cell to the top, so that the 'A's line up.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.mat-cell {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After Angular Material 15, according Angular documentation : https://material.angular.io/components/table/api

```
.mat-mdc-cell {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```